# Trying to setup a Maven Nexus Server but getting "Could not resolve dependencies"

Tags: java, maven, spring-webflow, nexus

Trying to setup a Maven Nexus Server but getting "Could not resolve dependencies" only on some of the packages.

Here is the output of my **mvn package**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building School Visit 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.414s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 25 12:42:45 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/100M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SchoolVisit: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.uftwf.schoolvisit:SchoolVisit:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Here is my settings.xml file:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>release</id>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/nexus-2.1.2/content/groups/public</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/nexus-2.1.2/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

and here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.uftwf.schoolvisit</groupId>
    <artifactId>SchoolVisit</artifactId>
    <name>School Visit</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.5</java-version>
        <springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        <springwebflow-version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</springwebflow-version>
        <springsecurity-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <!-- will come with all needed Spring dependencies such as spring-core 
                and spring-beans -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>${springwebflow-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF-303 Dependency Injection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Sun Mojarra JSF 2 runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSR 303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********************************************************************** 
            ** HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES ** ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Hibernate Validator -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Sun Mojarra JSF 2 implementation -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For PrimeFaces JSF component library -->

    </repositories>

    <build>

    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mode>both</mode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <server>6dvews01</server>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>

        <finalName>SchoolVisit</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can someone please tell me why I am geting this error.

Comment: Do you really need a snapshot dependency to spring-faces? Have you tried setting it to `2.3.1.RELEASE`? Snapshot dependencies [can be tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1683159/1434089)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your project or in your settings.xml file.

Maven will contact your localhost Nexus repository to look for `org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` and apparently is not finding it.

Does this artifact exist in your local Nexus repository? Do you have other repositories set up in your Nexus for it to go and fetch artifacts for which it does not have?

Comment: I have all the repositories setup in my nexuis

Comment: How are you verifying that `org.springframework.webflow:spring-faces:jar:2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` exists in the Nexus repo?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you actually want `2.3.1.RELEASE` not `2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`?